# How can I access Record Tags and/or Content tags via Apex & SOQL & SOSL

Tags: apex, soql, sosl, tag

I have a requirement to produce a unified search across Salesforce records using tags and documents in Content.   Both records and Content items may have received the same tag from a user and my unified search should bring both back when the user enters a Tag name (for example "sample_tag").

Question is using Apex&SOQL&SOSL how can I find records and / or Content items that have been tagged with "sample_tag".  I can't find any standard object that might hold the relationship.

Cheers

Comment: You can access normal objects (e.g. Account, Contact) through their respective tag objects (e.g. AccountTag, ContactTag). It appears that Content tags are only available through SOSL. A complete solution, then, would involve iterating through each taggable object, and running a SOQL for normal objects, and a SOSL for Content items. If there's an easier way to access this data, I don't know of it. I'm not making this an answer in case someone actually has one :p